# split string at first occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: bash, string

I do a grep in a shell (bash) to search for some ids in many log files:

```
grep "100200300" my.log*
```

result is something like that:

```
my.log:Jan 17 15:04:52 100200300 ok
my.log.1:Jan 17 14:35:17 100200300 failed
```

Now I want to remove the filename from the output. So how can I split this text at the first occurrence of the ":" and output the second part.

Comment: Just add the `-h` (`--no-filename`) option to grep if you don't want it to output the filename when given multiple files to search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As steeldriver commented, the preferred way is to use the `-h` (`--no-filename`) option. If your implementation of `grep` didn't include this option, you could use `sed` or `cut` to alter the output:

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...] | sed 's/[^:]*://'
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...] | cut -d : -f 2-
```

Note, however, that this solution is not general, as it breaks with filenames that contain a colon (`:`).

Answer (score 1):

This will do what the title of this question ask: 
    "split string at first occurrence of a delimiter"

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ :(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done <<<"$(grep "100200300" my.log*)"
```

However, I believe that what you need is:

```
grep -h "100200300" my.log*
```

The `-h` option will result in file contents **without** filenames:

```
Jan 17 15:04:52 100200300 ok
Jan 17 14:35:17 100200300 failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this to get rid of filenames:

```
cat my.log* | grep "100200300"
```